# gcc -m32 on 64 bit MacOs Lion

Tags: gcc, osx-lion, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to link two nasm 32 bit objects on a 64 bit intel Mac(Lion).

Used gcc -m32 and it is not working. I think It might be because I do not have the libraries installed. gcc-multilib. Do not know how to install them on Mac.

My gcc version: i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)

I just want it to work. Any suggestions would be useful, thanks!

Comment: I add how I compile the asm: nasm -f elf xxxx.asm

Comment: NASM version 0.98.40 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 11) compiled on Aug 11 2011

Answer (score 0):

On OS X, you don't use the `-m` switch. Instead, you use `-arch`. In this case: `-arch i386`.

Comment: Still not working: gcc -arch i386 -o ejecutable salida.o alfalib.o
ld: warning: ignoring file salida.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file alfalib.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

Comment: I think that's weird, because its is now linking in what it should but it doesn't recognize it... btw, -m32 works on mac